# Google sheets, make active range the top left cell of the window

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Essentially, I have a few sheets with the following setup:

A few frozen title rows at the top of the sheet, underneath that many rows of data all with a date in column A. The following function allows me to jump to 'today' on any sheet (well, technically the closest day in the future if there isn't data for today).

```
function goToToday() {
  var workbook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var currentSheet = workbook.getActiveSheet().getName();
  if (currentSheet !== "Calculations") {
    workbook.getSheetByName(currentSheet).setActiveRange(workbook.getSheetByName(currentSheet).getRange(1,1))
    var today = new Date()
    var rowNumber = 4
    var numOfRows = workbook.getSheetByName(currentSheet).getLastRow() - 3
    var dates = workbook.getSheetByName(currentSheet).getRange(4,1,numOfRows,1).getValues()
    for(i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++) {
      if(dates[i][0] > today) {
        break
      }
      else {
        rowNumber++
      }
    }
workbook.getSheetByName(currentSheet).getRange(rowNumber, 1).activate()
  }
}
```

What's bugging me is if active cell prior to running the function is *below* the returned 'today' cell of the function, the cell is returned as the top left cell in the window, which is perfect. If however the current active cell is *above* the returned cell, the cell is returned near the bottom of the window. How can I make the function return the cell consistently as the top left cell of the window? I assume this has something to do with scrolling..

Comment: why are you setting the active range to cell A1? Does it change the outcome at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function goToToday() {
  var workbook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      currentSheet = workbook.getActiveSheet();
  if ( currentSheet.getName() !== "Calculations" ) {
    var lastCell = currentSheet.getRange(
           currentSheet.getMaxRows(),getMaxColumns() 
    );
    currentSheet.setActiveRange("A1");
    var today = new Date(),
        rowNumber = 4,
        numOfRows = currentSheet.getLastRow() - 3,
        dates = currentSheet.getRange(4,1,numOfRows,1).getValues();
    for(i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++) {
      if(dates[i][0] > today) {
        break
      }
      else {
        rowNumber++
      }
    }
    currentSheet.setActiveRange(lastcell);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    currentSheet.getRange(rowNumber, 1).activate()
  }
}
```

I refactored some function calls, but the main idea is to set the active range to be the bottom right cell, flush the sheet (which should update the UI) and then set the active range to the target.

EDIT: In refactoring the OP's code, I moved the call to `.getName()` into the conditional, and just stored the sheet in `currentSheet`. This eliminated multiple calls to `worksheet.getSheetByName(currentSheet)`. Not a really big deal here, but in a larger script, run time would suffer. And, IMO, it's easier to read.

Comment: I had to change a few things, mainly around using the currentSheet variable but in principal your solution worked, thanks! For reference here is the functioning code:

EDIT: Too long for comment! :/

Comment: I used the currentSheet variable to store the sheet itself to eliminate the multiple calls to .getSheetByName(currentSheet). You only need the name of the sheet once, to ensure you're not in the Calculations sheet.

Comment: If you have a solution, post it as an answer. I'd like to see your code, and I can edit mine to make it work. I'd rather not have an answer that has code that doesn't work, especially if it's marked correct.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they are methods in Google Apps Script that can control the scroll, you can [request a new feature](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#missing-features).

A workaround (not the best one) is to use [hideRows()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hiderowsrowindex-numrows) and inmediately call [showRows()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hiderowsrowindex-numrows) that will make the UI "scroll". An example assuming the first row is frozen:

```
function myFunction() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
 sheet.hideRows(2, 199);
 sheet.showRows(2, 199);
 sheet.getRange(200, 2).activate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapting HardScale's solution, I got this to work. I'ts not the most well written and I'm sure there are plenty of ways to 'thin in out' so to speak, but it works!

```
function goToToday() {
  var workbook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var currentSheet = workbook.getActiveSheet().getName();
  if (currentSheet !== "Calculations") {
    var lastCell = workbook.getSheetByName(currentSheet).getRange(workbook.getSheetByName(currentSheet).getMaxRows(),workbook.getSheetByName(currentSheet).getMaxColumns());
    workbook.getSheetByName(currentSheet).setActiveRange(workbook.getSheetByName(currentSheet).getRange(1,1))
    var today = new Date()
    var rowNumber = 4
    var numOfRows = workbook.getSheetByName(currentSheet).getLastRow() - 3
    var dates = workbook.getSheetByName(currentSheet).getRange(4,1,numOfRows,1).getValues()
    for(i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++) {
      if(dates[i][0] > today) {
        break
      }
      else {
        rowNumber++
      }
    }
    workbook.getSheetByName(currentSheet).setActiveRange(lastCell);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
workbook.getSheetByName(currentSheet).getRange(rowNumber, 1).activate()
  }
}
```